(Python) Change the bone roll of a list of bones in variables
So I've had to store some bones in variables because I want to call on them even if they have slightly different names. I want to change the roll of a list of these bones, like this:
editbones = bpy.context.object.data.edit_bones
bone1 = editbones['bone1.L'] or editbones['bone1_L']
bone2 = editbones['bone2.L'] or editbones['bone2_L']
zero_roll = [bone1, bone2]
for b in editbones:
     if b in zero_roll:
          b.roll == 0

Why isn't this working? I know I could make a list of strings and loop through the bones to change the roll if the string in the list matches the bone name, but why can't I manipulate the roll of bones stored in variables like this?
